# <250 Best Beginner Functions

Tags: functions

Learning mma at the moment and made it into a side project to write a guide for high school students to get themselves up to speed with mma as a generic environment in preparation for a STEM degree.

I've finished a first draft and have about 50 functions that I 'needed' to get through a bunch of curriculum objectives (NZ based).  Functions like Table, Plot, RandomInteger, ListPlot etc are easy to discover and lead you into related functions.

I'm reaching out to see what the community thinks are really useful functions to know heading into university ie, turning 2 lists of x and y data into a single list of {x,y} is super easy *if* you know Transpose.

If you'd like to help, just chuck a function or two on [a Google form I just whipped up](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdxO1tm4DlyEZoQSvPLhlfToIhrhvI7Zo6vdWczN5wcweznZw/viewform?c=0&w=1).  I'll summarise and get back to you if/when I get some responses.